# Loop add UIImageView Cocoa Touch

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

having a problem adding multiple ImageViews to my view. I have an array of images and what to cycle through them and add to my view. This snippet adds an image to view, but with no frame!

```
- (void)cycleImages:(NSArray *)images {
    //create an image view

   int fromLeft = 5;
   int profilesCount = [images count] - 1;

    for(int n = 0; n <= profilesCount; n++){



       //add image view to view
       [self.view addSubview:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, fromLeft, 48, 48)] initWithImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[images objectAtIndex:n]]]]]];

        fromLeft = fromLeft + 53;

        NSLog(@"%d", fromLeft);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Dex

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to read such code and you have mem leaks. Please, try this.

```
- (void)cycleImages:(NSArray *)images 
{
   int fromLeft = 5;
   NSURL* url = nil;
   UIImage* img = nil;
   UIImageView* imgView = nil;
   NSData* imgData = nil;

   for (NSString* imgURLStr in images)//Using enumeration much more easy and in ObjC style
   {
       //Put breakpoint here and check all varibles initialized coorecly step by step
       url = [NSURL URLWithString:imgURLStr];
       imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
       img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
       imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];

       imgView.frame = CGRectMake(5, fromLeft, 48, 48);

       [self.view addSubView:imgView];

       fromLeft = fromLeft + 53;
       NSLog(@"%d", fromLeft);

       //Clean up
       [img release];
       [imgView release];
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Nice solution thank you, there is a typo in addSubView -> addSubview